# Unable to import Django model into Python shell

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am recently trying to lean APIs using DJango Rest. I have a model to work with:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

I want work with the model in the python shell, but whenever I do:

```
from polls.models import Poll
```

in python shell, it shows:

```
Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define
the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

could anyone help?
I am also working on a virtual env

Comment: How do you launch the Python shell? You should use `manage.py shell`.

Comment: yep this solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the shell using just 'python shell'. Apparently, I just realized I need to open it with 'python manage.py shell'

Thanks @Seluk for the comment